# Wifi card not working with Debian on Thinkpad e590

Tags: debian, thinkpad, firmware, iwlwifi

I'm attempting to setup a new Debian install on a Lenovo Thinkpad E590, and I've been having quite a bit of trouble with the wifi drivers. I've installed the `iwlwifi` set of firmware, yet `iwconfig` and Network Manager still seem to have trouble recognizing the card. I'm also getting some conflicting reports from other commands as well.

The wifi card in the laptop is Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260, which the `iwlwifi` docs list as fully supported. I already attempted the fix of changing `managed=false` to `managed=true` in `NetworkManager.conf`, but that has no effect. At the moment, the NM applet dropdown flashes between "device not ready" and "device not managed" under the Wifi Networks section.

Here's the printout of a couple commands:

```
trenza@thinky:~$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp4s0    no wireless extensions.

trenza@thinky:~$ sudo ifconfig
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.3.127  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 172.17.3.255
        inet6 fe80::9afa:9bff:fe4d:33c5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 98:fa:9b:4d:33:c5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 59862  bytes 24210568 (23.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 386  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16145  bytes 1862668 (1.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 335  bytes 30845 (30.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 335  bytes 30845 (30.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

trenza@thinky:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:2526] (rev 29)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 [8086:0014]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

trenza@thinky:~$ nmcli
enp4s0: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8169), 98:FA:9B:4D:33:C5, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 172.17.3.127/22
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 169.254.0.0/16
        route4 172.17.0.0/22
        inet6 fe80::9afa:9bff:fe4d:33c5/64
        route6 fe80::/64
        route6 ff00::/8

wlp5s0: unavailable
        "Intel Wireless-AC 9260"
        wifi (iwlwifi), 6A:AF:F8:AC:97:AD, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 10.1.2.2 10.1.2.17
        interface: enp4s0
lines 1-23
 use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

trenza@thinky:~$ nmcli
enp4s0: connected to Wired connection 1
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8169), 98:FA:9B:4D:33:C5, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 172.17.3.127/22
        route4 0.0.0.0/0
        route4 169.254.0.0/16
        route4 172.17.0.0/22
        inet6 fe80::9afa:9bff:fe4d:33c5/64
        route6 fe80::/64
        route6 ff00::/8

wlp5s0: unavailable
        "Intel Wireless-AC 9260"
        wifi (iwlwifi), 6A:AF:F8:AC:97:AD, hw, mtu 1500

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 10.1.2.2 10.1.2.17
        interface: enp4s0
```

Anyone have ideas of what else I should try? happy to provide more info as well, as I'm sure there's something I've forgotten to paste in here. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue, when executing the command I usually got:

```
Direct firmware load for iwlfiwi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode failed with error -2
```

So what I did is the following:

Add the following to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
```

Then execute the following commands:

```
apt update && apt install firmware-iwlwifi
```

Once done download the ucode of the Intel® Wireless-AC 9260:
[Intel Wireless-AC 9260 Linux drivers](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)

Next unzip the archive and place the ucode firmware in /lib/firmware

Then execute the following commands:

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
reboot
```

Once rebooted, my laptop was finally able to recognize the card and connect to wifi network.