# WiFi Card not Working

Tags: arch-linux

I have a Intel 9260 installed.  I went through dmesg, and saw that it tried the iwlwifi-9260...-34, which from here (https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi?s[]=iwlwifi&s[]=9260), shows that it should be the right driver for it.  It shows that it failed "with error -2".  How can I get this to work with my Wireless card?

Request to try: [Wifi card not working with Debian on Thinkpad e590](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/538777/100397)
Response: I tried that.  I could not modify /sys/firmware, so I tried to reboot onto USB to modify it, but it no longer existed there.  I then copied the ucode to /usr/lib/modules/5.6.7-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/firmware.  I rebooted, ran those commands again, then rebooted, but still no luck.

The reason I tried /sys/firmware was because that was 1 of 2 findings for 'firmware' that I could locate on the system.

Comment: Related - [Wifi card not working with Debian on Thinkpad e590](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/538777/100397)

Comment: I tried that.  I could not modify /sys/firmware, so I tried to reboot onto USB to modify it, but it no longer existed there.  I then copied the ucode to /usr/lib/modules/5.6.7-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/firmware.  I rebooted, ran those commands again, then rebooted, but still no luck.

Comment: Please add that to your question so people don't have to wade through comments to piece all the information together

Comment: Please also explain (in your question) the relevance of `/sys/firmware` here (the related question's answer doesn't mention it that i can see). In fact i can't see the relevance of `/usr/lib/modules/5.6.7-arch1-1/kernel/drivers/firmware` either. It seems to me you haven't followed the instructions

Comment: I am not running a Debian system, and do not have apt.  Also, the file structure/hierarchy is not the same.

Comment: You need to install the `linux-firmware` package, see  package contents https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/any/linux-firmware/

Comment: I tried pacstrap and pacman, and both throw the same error: "error: command failed to execute properly"